# Reduction of vanadyl ion

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, experimental-chemistry, electrolysis, reduction-potential

I want to reduce vanadyl to vanadium (III), can somebody please suggest some appropriate methods for it? I am trying to make a redox flow battery for a project but I have only vanadyl sulfate.

Comment: Have you consulted a table of reduction potentials such as [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_electrode_potential_(data_page)#cite_note-CRC-1)?

Comment: http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Inorganic_Chemistry/Descriptive_Chemistry/d-Block_Elements/Group_05%3A_Transition_Metals/Chemistry_of_Vanadium

Comment: http://chemed.chem.purdue.edu/demos/main_pages/12.7.html

Comment: my guess is that in acidic environment it should be easily reduced. So, 2VOSO4/H2SO4  + reducer should do the trick. Maybe, oxalic acid in boiling diluted acid?